# Integrating .jar in a flash project

Tags: java, flash, jar, voice, executable-jar

I must integrate a .jar file into a flash project. The project is like this:

There'll be a flash video player for a Web Browser with Play, Pause, Stop commands. I must use voice commands to trigger the player actions. I have a .jar that makes the voice recognition so I want to integrate this file with my Flash Player.

Is this possible?

P.S.: You may wonder why I don't use other tools, but it's a project for University with given materials, so I really need to use Flash + this given .jar .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flash player can't execute the Java byte code in your jar.  You can create a Java based web service that uses the jar to analyse the audio on the server side.  This would require recording the audio in flash, and sending it to the server.